# Definition of quadratic variation in Protter

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I'm reading Chapter 2 of Protter's *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*, Version 2.1.  The definition of quadratic variation of a semi-martingale boils down to
\begin{equation*}
[X,X]_{t} = X_{0}^{2} + \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{2^{n} - 1} (X_{(i + 1) t2^{-n}} - X_{it2^{-n}})^{2},
\end{equation*}
where the limit is in probability.  The key point is the $X_{0}^{2}$ term.  If $X$ and $Y$ are semi-martingales, $[X,Y]$ is defined similarly (or by polarization).

Later, Theorem 29 effectively states that
\begin{equation}
[H \cdot X, Y]_{t} = \int_{(0,t]} H_{s} d[X,Y]_{s},
\end{equation}
provided $H$ is caglad and adapted.  (Here $H \cdot X$ is the stochastic integral of $H$ with respect to $X$, and both $X$ and $Y$ are semi-martingales.)

My question is: where has the $H_{0} X_{0} Y_{0}$ term gone?  I suspect this is a typo and it should read
\begin{equation*}
[H\cdot X,Y]_{t} = \int_{(0,t]} H_{s} d[X,Y]_{s} + H_{0} X_{0} Y_{0}.
\end{equation*}
Otherwise, taking $H \equiv 1$ in Theorem 29, one would obtain
\begin{equation*}
[X,Y]_{t} = \int_{(0,t]} d[X,Y]_{s} = [X,Y]_{t} - [X,Y]_{0} = [X,Y]_{t} - X_{0} Y_{0}.
\end{equation*}

One answer could be "caglad implies zero at $t = 0$" (which is philosophically consistent with the book's convention that $H_{0^{-}} = 0$).  But when Protter defines "simple predictable processes," he allows their value at $0$ to be a random variable.

Am I missing something?  This is the corrected second edition of the book so I'm willing to believe it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not $H_0X_0Y_0$ that you would expect, but $(H\cdot X)_0Y_0$, which is $0$ as $(H\cdot X)_0=0$.

Comment: My understanding is, with Protter's definitions, $(H \cdot X)_{0} = H_{0} X_{0}$ if $H$ is a "simple predictable process" (pp. 58), hence also if $H$ is caglad and adapted (by approximation).

Comment: So for instance $\int_0^TdX_t$ is not $X_T-X_0$ but $X_T$? And $\int_0^0dX_t$ is not $0$ but $X_0$?

Comment: Yes, that does appear to be the case --- your question is more-or-less equivalent to my original one, though.  (Theorem 21 even uses the notation "$\int_{0^{+}}^{t} Y_{s} dX_{s}$", presumably to clarify that the term $Y_{0} X_{0}$ shouldn't be there in this instance...)  I don't understand the choice of definitions in this book, and Theorem 29 seems to be inconsistent with these definitions in particular.